# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" when creating NSDictionary with tweets

Tags: ios, twitter, unrecognized-selector

I'm searching Twitter for tweets with this code:

```
- (void)fetchTweets
{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json"];
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"#winning" forKey:@"q"];

TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url 
                                         parameters:params 
                                      requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

[request performRequestWithHandler:
 ^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

     if (responseData) {
         NSError *jsonError;
         tweets = 
         [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
                                         options:kNilOptions
                                           error:&jsonError];


         if (tweets) {
            // NSLog(@"%@", tweets);
         } 

         else { 
             NSLog(@"%@", jsonError);
         }

     }

     [[self delegate] receivedTweets];

 }];

[self performSelector:@selector(fetchTweets) withObject:nil afterDelay:30];
```

The tweets variable is a NSArray and I am trying to put it into a NSDictionary with this code:

```
NSDictionary *tweet = [[TwitterHandler sharedInstance].tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I am definitely getting the JSON text for the tweets but when trying to add them to the dictionary so I can eventually put them into a table I get the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error.

I am not sure why I am getting this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the actual error message?  It should have the name of the selector and the type of instance.

Comment: @PhillipMills `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdec1140'`

Comment: Either your tweets array is being deallocated and the memory has been re-used to hold a dictionary or maybe `JSONObjectWithData` **returned** a dictionary.  When you had `// NSLog(@"%@", tweets);` uncommented, what did it say?

Comment: The log gave me the JSON formatted tweets I was searching for.

Comment: But did it show them as being in an array or a dictionary???

Comment: It is showing them as a dictionary

Comment: OK...then the problem is that a dictionary really doesn't know how to get `objectAtIndex:`.

Comment: I guess I am confused as to how tweets is being displayed as a dictionary when I've declared it as an array

Comment: J_D's edit below!  How you declare it doesn't change what it is internally and what methods it understands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
                                options:kNilOptions
                                  error:&jsonError];
```

This returns an NSDictionary object of the tweets. The Twitter search results from that URL can be filtered out by looking for the content in the key `results`.

AKA:

```
NSDictionary *jsonTweet = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
                                                          options:kNilOptions
                                                          error:&jsonError];

NSArray *tweet = [jsonTweet objectForKey:@"results"];
```

Then the tweets can be iterated through since they are in an NSArray.

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
 if (responseData) {
         NSError *jsonError;
         tweets = 
         [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
                                         options:kNilOptions
                                           error:&jsonError];


         if (tweets) {
            // NSLog(@"%@", tweets);
         } 

         else { 
             NSLog(@"%@", jsonError);
         }
```

Is `tweets` the same that you are getting with this code:

```
[[TwitterHandler sharedInstance].tweets
```

If so, it seems to me that you are assigning it to au autoreleased object, so it will eventually be released and you will end-up with a pointer to a released object.

Better retain it or use a retain property when assigning it.

Something like

```
tweets = 
         [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
                                         options:kNilOptions
                                           error:&jsonError] retain];
```

or, assuming that `tweets` is a retain orpperty:

```
self.tweets = 
         [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
                                         options:kNilOptions
                                           error:&jsonError];
```

Do not forget to release it when it is no longer needed (at least in the `dealloc` of your class)

**EDIT**

Ok, here is the thing, and it has nothing to do with memory management (wrong initial guess!): I tried your URL, and it returns:

```
{"error":"You must enter a query."}
```

Which is a JSon dictionary. Then the JSON Parser identifies this as a dictionary and returns you a dictionary. You may store it in a NSArray*, but the object instantiated is still a dictionary, and will only responds to the NSDictionary methods. As you comment shows when you print it, it prints a dictionary.

Comment: I am using ARC so I cannot use the retain property. I've tried `self.tweets` but I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: I am not very familiar with ARC, apart from basically knowing what it does, but is there a way to differentiate properties that assign or retain the objects? Because for the self.tweets to work, the property tweets should be declared as a retain property, with code similar to (in non-ARC): @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary * tweets;

Comment: I have it declared as `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *tweets;`

Comment: I have added an edit, explaining why you receive a dictionary, which does not responds to the NSArray call you are trying to use.

Comment: Very helpful to know. I will try adding into my table with a NSDictionary method.

Comment: You should check what is the JSon format that you receive. I do not know the twitter API, but for successful requests, it seems to put all tweets in an array, this array is under the key "results" of the big dictionary you receive as an answer (based on an example I found by Googling).

Answer (score 1):

I had this once and it was the app releasing the view controller, check if your view controller is being released.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not being released

Comment: only perform the code that is causing the error if objectatindex is `!= nil` so that there won't be an error

Comment: This will not help, as it is the call to objectAtIndex that crashes. Furthermore, there is no harm, in Objective-C, to call a method on a nil object. It will simply do nothing and return nil/0 if it has to return something.